# Incorrect relative path in java

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-14

My issue is in the code here (seperated for debugging purposes):

```
// creating newUniversePane
Scene newUniverseScene = new Scene(newUniversePane, 300, 200);
Class<? extends WorldNoteOrganizerMainController> aClass = getClass();
URL resource = aClass.getResource("../../resources/css/main.css");
String s = resource.toExternalForm();
newUniverseScene.getStylesheets().add(s);
//more code
```

So, by looking at many examples here on Stack Overflow, it seems that my relative path is correct. However, when I run the program, and it reaches this code, it gives me an error.(I am attempted to add the css to a scene which will be added to a Stage as a popup)

Error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   controller.WorldNoteOrganizerMainController.handleNewUniverse(WorldNoteOrganizerMainController.java:169)

This error points to the line:

```
String s = resource.toExternalForm();
```

which is because resource is null. I have tried many different paths to try to get the file, but have not been successful. Also, I looked around on here, so that I am not repeating a question, but I could not find any questions that would help. I found relative class path questions, but they did not help me fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have added relative information to the end.

Actual one-liner code:

```
newUniverseScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/../../resources/css/main.css").toExternalForm();
```

Paths tried:

```
URL resource = aClass.getResource("/../resources/css/main.css");
URL resource = aClass.getResource("/resources/css/main.css");
```

Snapshot of hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: IntelliJ has some troubles with correctly setting up the classpath in a few versions...

Comment: You need to find out what folder your app is at, when it runs, and how you look it up.  Using `this.getClass().getResource()` the lookup is relative to the location of the class file itself, _if the path begins with anything other than "/"_,  When the path begins with "/", it is assumed to be an "absolute" path, and it will start at the "top" of the classpath (which in Eclipse ought to be the "target" folder).  So - in you case, you would probably need to use "../src/main/resources/css/main.css", or better yet, "/css/main.css" (since src/main/resources/* will be copied to target/)

Comment: getResource does not support `..` in paths. Read the javadoc. The correct path is "/css/main.css". https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html. src/main/resources is a root of the package tree, just as src/main/java.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input! JB Nizet and moilejter, your comments fixed my error (switching to "/css/main.css")! This opened up more problems with different questions, but now it is time to figure them out myself! If you make it an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out what folder your app is at, when it runs, and how you look it up. Using `this.getClass().getResource()` the lookup is relative to the location of the class file itself, if the path begins with anything other than "/", When the path begins with "/", it is assumed to be an "absolute" path, and it will start at the "top" of the classpath (which in Eclipse ought to be the "target" folder). So - in you case, you would probably need to use "/css/main.css" (since src/main/resources/* will be copied to target/) - and as pointed out below, "relative paths" do not make sense here.

Comment: As requested ;-p

Comment: no .. you would _never_ use "../somepath" - what can be resolved is clearly specified at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

When you are using relative path, use this:

```
aClass.getClassLoader().getResource("relative-path");
```

If you are using Intellij there is an option that gives you the relative path by right clicking on the file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the Intellij tip!

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the resources folder as a resource folder in `Inillj IDEA` (the yellow little icon) then call `getClass().getResources()` it gets you inside the resources directory itself so you just use `getClass().getResources("css/main.css")`